# Write to a php file via wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I've built a web page that is able to send text messages to employees at the company where I work. With new employees being added and removed on a constant basis, I want to integrate this app with wordpress where the employees can be managed without editing the code.

Each post would contain the user's name and phone number. The name would be pulled in on the webpage as an option for the user to contact. When the form is submitted, it would go to a php form that runs an if/else to find the employee and match that employee with their phone number like so:

```
//Who the text message is to, Establish their phone #
if($employee == 'brad'):
     $text_to[] = '+15555555555';
elseif ($employee == 'mary'):
     $text_to[] = '+15555555555'; 
elseif ($employee == 'tom'):
     $text_to[] = '+15555555555'; 
elseif ($employee == 'bill'):
     $text_to[] = '+15555555555'; 
elseif ($employee == 'joe'):
endif;
```

I want to be able to not only pull these names from wordpress via a loop to display onto my page, ***but also to be able to add or remove the new entries, along with their phone number, to this php contact form***.

I know how to loop through the wordpress posts to display the names on the page. I want to know if it's possible to also use this data to modify this contact form, and if so, how to set this up. Each time someone edits the wordpress entry for Joe, the PHP form gets this update so that when Joe is sent a message, it finds his phone number and sends him the message.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I should also note that I'm using Twilio to send the texts messages.

Comment: Why don't you just save the phone number as a meta value? It would be attached to the employee, so you could just use `get_post_meta()` without having to do any conditionals...

Comment: @rnevius, `get_post_meta` is a poor solution since it would require each employee to have his/her own post.  This is surely unmanageable and awkward.  It would be much better to have all this data stored on a database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So everything that you all suggested was helpful. I may have not been as clear as I could have that I really needed the creation/editing/deletion of entries to be done via wordpress posts. I was able to set it up like this by doing the following:

```
//pull variables from html form input. Employee variables are post ID's that I will then be able to use to retrieve the post_content which contains their phone numbers
   $employee1 = $_POST['employeeName1'];
   $employee2 = $_POST['employeeName2'];
   $employee3 = $_POST['employeeName3'];
   $customMsg = $_POST["textMessage"];

//Create array from above variables and exclude any that lack post data
$employees = array($employee1, $employee2, $employee3);
$setEmployeeIDs = array();
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
    if (!empty($employee)) {
        $setEmployeeIDs[] = $employee;
    }
}

$servername = "xxxx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//Get array of Phone Numbers connected to each ID and add to array
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN (".implode(',',$setEmployeeIDs).")";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$phoneNumbers = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $phoneNumbers[] = $row["post_content"] ;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

So to sum it up, I used wordpress to publish/edit/delete that data as posts, then sent the ID's selected from the webpage to the php form, and then was able to retrieve the phone numbers from the SQL database using Raphael's direction.

Comment: Also I realize the title of this question is misleading. Should be "How to pull SQL data based on Post ID in PHP Contact Form" rather than "Write to a php file via wordpress". However, I didn't really know that would be the direction I needed to go until Raphael posted his answer and sent me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos for trying to solve a simple problem yourself.  It's obvious that you are new to the idea of databases, and quite frankly, you're doing this the wrong way.

Let's talk about how your initial approach can be improved:

> Each post would contain the user's name and phone number.

Perhaps instead of posts, we have one database table to store employee information.

You'll find tons of information on databases and how to use them with your wordpress account with a simple google search.

> I want to be able to not only pull these names from wordpress via a loop to display onto my page, but also to be able to add or remove the new entries, along with their phone number, to this php contact form.

Again, if you had a database to store employee information, this is basic.

For example, an `employees` database table may have the following columns:

- id
- name
- phone
- created_at
- updated_at

Since `PHP` has built in functions for communicating with a `MYSQL` database (which is most likely what WordPress is already using), you can do things like:

Get all employee data

`SELECT * FROM employees`

Get a certain employee's data

`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = '$name'`

`$name` is a variable that can be set via `POST` request from a WordPress form

Update a certain employee's data

`UPDATE employees SET phone = '+15555555555' WHERE name = '$name'`

Remove a certain employee's data

`DELETE FROM employees WHERE id = 5`

You are also able to do things like:

`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE created_at > '3/1/2015'`

Which will return all employees that were added after `3/1/15`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to spell this out for me. I'm still digesting what you wrote, but if I understand your solution, you are suggesting that I manually create a database, then manually edit that database entries. Is that correct? If so, would it be possible to instead just use the existing database that wordpress is using to store post data to pull this information into the contact form? That would be ideal since I want any WP user to be able to create/edit/delete these database entries via the post.

Comment: @davevsdave, you can either create a new database or use the existing database.  A database can have many tables.  A table can be something like `employees` and columns of that table can be `id`, `name`, etc.  WordPress has many tables including a table for posts, another one for users, another for comments, etc.  What I am suggesting is to create a table for employees, create a wordpress form to add/update/delete an employee.  Then you can pull this information into your contact form.  Basically, you wanted to write to a php file.  Instead, write to a database.  Pull from that database.

Comment: Also, if you are unaware how to handle a `POST` request from a wordpress form, take a look at this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)

Comment: And if you are new to form actions, take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: To be clear, you will manually create the table, but you will never manually write/edit/update it.  All database table changes will be done automatically through user input.  If a user wants to add an employee, he/she would fill out a form and click the submit button. The newly added employee will be in the database table and as a result, can be messaged. You would have to implement the form handler yourself.  I would suggest learning how this is generally done via pure html and php and then once you understand that, move on to learning wordpress best practices. Also, you're welcome. =)

Answer (score 0):

The use of a DMBS works well, but is not the only solution.

include 'users.inc'; // flat file creating array $userList
which could be an array( ofArrays ) for complex structures

[assume $userList = array($user => $phone, ...); ]
then foreach( $userList as $user => $phone  ) { // process($user, $phone); }

Comment: This is a poor solution since this php file would still need to be updated as employees are added, edited and removed, and it is much easier to do this with a database.

Comment: agree, but regardless, something has to be update and a flat file is easily exported to other standalone locations.  To my mind, the issue of selectivity is a much bigger problem, ergo <code>SELECT username, phone FROM users
  WHERE
    dept = "xxx" 
  AND
    location = "yyy"
  ;</code>

Comment: Are you suggesting that it is hard to query a database? Are you also suggesting that databases are difficult to export?

Comment: Neither - - just more work to do.  My comment re selectivity was aimed at the flat file solution :)